# for(int : array) index out of bounds exception

Tags: java

I have been learning Java recently and I cam across an issue today to which I couldn't find a working solution.
My code looks like this:

```
public class testTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bob[] = {456,2,3,4,5,6};

    for(int j : bob) {
        System.out.println(bob[j]);
    }



  }

}
```

The code always returns the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 456
at com.Practice.thenewboston.Arrays.Table.testTable.main(testTable.java:9)
```

Any help would be appreciated and a good explanation as to why the error occurs would be nice. 
Thanks!

Comment: You reference arrays by providing an index of the location you want to get the value from. And these indexes start with zero. So to get the first value, you would do `bob[0]`. What that for-loop is doing is automatically going through each element of the array, and one-by-one, putting the value into `j`. So to print out the value, you just do `System.out.println(j);`

Comment: Ohhh Okay. Thanks alot that's something that wasn't covered in my class.

Comment: I put my comment as an answer. I hope this helps you out :-) If not, add a new comment to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference arrays by providing an index of the location you want to get the value from. And these indexes start with zero. So to get the first value from the array, you would do `bob[0]`. What that `for-loop` is doing is automatically going through each element of the array, and one-by-one, putting the value into `j`. So to print out the value, you just do `System.out.println(j);`

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(j);` is what you need for the type of for loop(Enhanced for loop) you are using.

```
for(int j : bob) {
        System.out.println(j);
}
```

or

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < bob.length ; j++) {
        System.out.println(bob[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your loop should be like this

```
  for(int j : bob) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

this works for collections

Comment: Since they mentioned they are learning Java, would be good to include a WHY you are providing that answer.

Answer (score -1):

> try this...
>    First element of your array is 456 and your `array length` is `6`, So, you are trying to access the index which is not **exists** in `array`. So, it causes IndexOutOfBoundException..

```
 public class testTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bob[] = {456,2,3,4,5,6};

    for(int j : bob) {  //this is foreach not for loop be aware.
        System.out.println(j);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can think of it as a for-each, but it is still a for-loop. It's called an Enhanced for-loop